# View full Grid item when modified GridView template

Tags: gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, datatemplate

I have this xaml code:

```
                <local:MyGridView x:Name="topDeal" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="60,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate> 
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding image1}"/>
                                </Grid.Background>

                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#0072B0" Opacity="0.6">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="white"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="180" ItemWidth="180" Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </local:MyGridView>
```

and c# code behind:

```
public class MyGridView : GridView
{

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var gi = element as GridViewItem;
        //First griditem of MyGridView will be modified
        if (this.Items.IndexOf(item) == 0)
        {
            gi.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
            gi.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 2);
        }
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(gi, item);
    }
}
```

I want to to make first item show in double size of other items with a background image in it. The result in this  [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxZlS.jpg). The background image was only fill in TextBlock.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data template you can try this way and it should work for you if I'm not wrong :

```
`<Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,80"><Image Source="{Binding Image}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/></Border>`
```

Comment: Thanks, i found another solution. Im using  <Image VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/> instead of <Grid.Background> and <ImageBrush>